# Regular expressions : how to find

Tags: c#, regex

Why doesn't this regex, constructed like this:

```
tmprect = string "gg_rct_MyReg1"
regex = @"^\s*set\s+"+tmprect+@"\s*=\s*Rect\s*\(\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*,\s*(.+)\s*,\s**(.+)\s*\).*$";
```

not work for

```
set gg_rct_MyReg1 = Rect (-704.0 ,   -352.0, 224.0   , 448.0) //rect 1
```

What did I do wrong?

///edited:

```
string findrectcoord = @"^\s*set\s+" + tmprect + @"\s*=\s*Rect\s*\(\s*([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*([^)\s]*)\s*\).*$";
StreamReader file3 = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string line2;
while ((line2 = file3.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Regex foundrectr = new Regex(findrectcoord);
    Match foundrectm = foundrectr.Match(line2);
      if (foundrectm.Success)
       {
         MessageBox.Show("YES");

       }
  }
```

string:

```
set gg_rct_MyReg1 = Rect( -704.0  ,  -352.0, 224.0  , 288.0 ) //JassCode
```

Not Found

Comment: This question is not correctly wrote. :-)

Comment: What are you trying to do with your regex? You need to give more information - "here is what I want to happen, and here is what is happening". Simple is better.

Comment: regex doesn't work for these data.

string " set gg_rct_MyReg1 = Rect (-704.0, -352.0, 224.0, 448.0) //rect 1"

I need to find coordinates.

Comment: Is `tmprect` properly escaped to be included in a regex? See `Regex.Escape`.

Comment: Try pasting that at [regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/)

Comment: Obviously a problem with `tmprect`.

Comment: Are you assigning `tmprect` after you've built the regex?

Comment: Absolutely useless site! :(

Comment: @ZeroMemory: You're not giving us enough information to answer in a meaningful way. I'll try anyway.

Comment: There is a line: "set gg_rct_MyReg1 = Rect (-704.0  ,   -352.0,   224.0, 448.0) //rect 1"  It is necessary to find coordinates. (the code is available, but regex can't find coordinate)

Comment: @ZeroMemory You have an issue with asking questions. The site is made to clear up "bad quality" questions/answers and leave the good ones. I see that you're trying, that's why I'll try to give you a solution :)

Comment: I provided all information :)

String in which it is necessary to find coordinates, but does not work regex which need to be corrected :)

Comment: @ZeroMemory As promised, here's a [regex](http://regex101.com/r/bM2yT0), I wrote it from zero: `set\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*Rect\s*\(\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*\)`.

Comment: @ZeroMemory: I doubt it. What you posted shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Is your code supposed to be pseudocode or a real language? Because it's not valid C#.

Comment: set gg_rct_MyReg1 = Rect( -704.0, -352.0, 224.0, 288.0 ) --- Jass code

Comment: `Absolutely useless site!` How appreciative of you. ~10 different people here trying to get you a solution, but yes, it's a useless site, considering you got an answer here as well. Frankly, I don't know why people bother with posters like you. I guess they have more patience than I do.

Comment: How to ask a new question? :)  button does not work: (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex itself, while ugly and inefficient, should work. You do need to assign the string you're adding into the regex before building the regex, though. While we're at it, let's clean it up:

```
string tmprect = "gg_rct_MyReg1";
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^\s*set\s+" + tmprect + 
                           @"\s*=\s*Rect\s*\(\s*([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*([^,\s]*)\s*,\s*([^)\s]*)\s*\).*$");
```

`([^,\s]*)` matches any number of characters except commas or spaces. That is more specific than `.*` which will match too much and force the regex engine to backtrack.